# SEO - how to get rid of duplicate web URLs

Tags: seo, url

On my webpage I have nice URL addresses like this:

```
example.com/category
```

Then I have some filter which adds to the URL address a string, the URL address then looks like this:

```
example.com/category/?type=1
```

The problem is than on Google I can see these results:

```
example.com/category/?type=1
example.com/category/?type=2
example.com/category/?type=
```

etc.

How could I get rid of these duplicities please?
Thanks.

Comment: When you say "get rid of" do you mean that you don't want users to find them, or that you don't want search engines to index them?

Comment: Do all `...type=2, ...type=` give the same page of `myweb.com/category/?type=1`?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using canonical URL tags. Moz has a [great guide to the basics](https://moz.com/blog/canonical-url-tag-the-most-important-advancement-in-seo-practices-since-sitemaps).

What you would do is apply a canonical URL tag to the original page in the `<head>` section like so:

`<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/category" />`

Then apply the exact same tag to the duplicate pages. Depending on how the duplicate pages are generated the method of doing this will be different.

What this does is indicate to search engines like Google that `example.com/category` is the one true version of the page in a manner of speaking and that any SEO factors from the duplicate pages should be applied to this original page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about 'SEO friendly' URLs, sometimes known as permalinks.

Here's an article I found with a quick search, but it is 3 years old, so may be out of date.  https://www.script-tutorials.com/permalinks-tutorial/